# How to differenciate XmlHttpRequest Access-Control-Allow-Origin errors from simple network errors

Tags: javascript, ajax

When sending an ajax request one may get an error, which means no communication could be established with target (i.e. no status code returned)

We can catch these errors like this:

```
var oXhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
oXhr.addEventListener("error",function (e) {
    //error code
});
```

But these errors can be of at least 2 different types:

- You just got disconnected and you get a network error
- The target disallows ajax request from a different origin (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`)

Although I get a red message in Chrome console, I can't get the actual message programatically.

I tried:

- xhr.responseText
- parsing the event itself

I would like to avoid pinging my own server to discard the network error...

Answer (score 0):

You can check the property `status` of your instance of `XMLHttpRequest`. If it is equal to `XMLHttpRequest.UNSENT` or `0`, then some kind of error different than a network error occurred, possibly a violation of the Same origin policy.